# If a function is Lipschitz, and differentiable, is its gradient also Lipschitz?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

If $f(x)$ is Lipschitz, i.e. 
$$||f(x) - f(y)|| \le L||x-y||$$ is it's gradient also Lipschitz?

$$||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \le K||x - y|| $$

And does $L = K$ ?

Comment: The gradient need not even exist.

Comment: Maybe you mean: If $f$ is differentiable with gradient bounded by $K$, then $L=K$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm assuming there is a gradient for the entire domain of the function.

Comment: @MF14 nope. I mean what I wrote.

Comment: Ok, so $L \ne K$, an example of this is $f(x) = \sqrt{||x||^2 + a^2}$ who's Lipschitz constant is 1, but gradient Lipschitz constant is $\frac{1}{a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering a function which depends only on the first coordinate you can reduce this to a question on the real line.

Let $h$ be an intergable function on $\mathbb R$ which is not bounded. Let $g(x)=\int_0^{x} h(t)dt$ and $f(x)=\int_0^{x} g(t)dt$. Since $f$ has  a bounded derivative (namely $g$) we see that $f$ is Lipschitz. However $f'=g$ is not Lipschitz: If it is Lipschitz then $h$ would be bounded since $g'=h$ almost everywhere.

Comment: can you give an example of an actual function?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli Take $h(x)=\frac  1 {\sqrt x}$ for $o<x<1$ and $0$ for all other $x$. This function is intergrable but not bounded. It is easy to calculate $g$ and $f$ from this. If you do that you will get an explicit example.

Comment: I don't understand. If you take $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ then it's derivative is not bounded, and nor does it's 2nd derivative - $0.75x^{-0.5}$

Comment: Did you read my comment correctly? The derivative of $x^{3/2}$ is surely bounded on $(0,1)$. My function $h$ is $0$ outside this  interval.

Comment: oh right - I missed the domain.